# Kotlin Calling Companion Object in Abstract Class

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a class, `Base` that is an abstract class and is defined as:

```
abstract class Base() {}
```

I'd like to create a handful of derived classes from this base class:

```
class A : Base() {}
class B : Base() {}
class C : Base() {}
```

I would like to be able to call a common function `create` that does some initialization work and returns the specified derived class (e.g. `A`). For example, something like the following would be ideal:

```
val a = A.create() // `a` now holds an instance of `A`.
val b = B.create()
val c = C.create()
```

Initially I tried to use a companion object in the abstract class as a sort of static funcion:

```
abstract class Base {
    companion object {
        fun create() : Base { 
            // Do some initialization and return the derived class
            // of the object. Obviously I can't return `Base` as I've
            // indicated above since it is an abstract class. This is
            // what I'm confused about: How do I return a copy of the
            // _derived_ class here? Is this impossible? I think it
            // might be...
            return Base() // <-- This doesn't work. What should be returned?
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the derived class:

```
class A : Base() {
    companion object {
        fun create() : A = Base.create()
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, for obvious reasons. Namely, I can't return an instance of the abstract class `Base`. Is there an easy way to accomplish the `var a = A.create()` paradigm? The code for `create` will be identical across derived classes, so I wanted to avoid having to recreate the functionality in each class I create.

Comment: "The code for create will be identical across derived classes" Well, how is _that_ possible? If the code is completely identical, so is the return type.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov That's kind of what I'm getting at. The return type is something that inherits from `Base`. Perhaps a better phrasing is "The boilerplate code for `create` needs to do the same thing each time, but for different derived classes". I can't make the return type `Base` as that would imply creating an instance of a derived class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the initialization logic is the same and is based on the functionality specified in the `Base` class you can also do it like this:

```
abstract class Base() {

    protected fun init(): Base {
        // do the initialization
        return this
    }
}

class A : Base() {
    companion object {
        fun create() = A().init() as A
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
abstract class Base {
    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T : Base> create() : T { 
            // you can use T::class here
        }
    }
}

class A : Base() {
    companion object {
        fun create() : A = Base.create() // inferred to Base.create<A>()
    }
}
```

may work but probably need to use unsafe reflection. It depends on what exactly you want to do in `create`... A better practice would be to pass whatever is different between the classes as a function, e.g.

```
abstract class Base {
    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T : Base> create(f: () -> T) : T { 
            val instance = f()
            // do something
            return instance // or something created from it
        }
    }
}

class A : Base() {
    companion object {
        fun create() : A = Base.create { A() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Based on this answer I could made my own inline reified companion function to create a instance of my project without unsafe reflection!

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming your classes share a constructor with the same argument list.
What you then can do is define a trait

```
trait Instantiation[K] {

  def newWith(args):K
}
```

have your classes implement this

```
class A implements Instantiation[A] {
  override def newWith(args):A
}

class B implements Instantiation[B] {
  override def newWith(args):B
}

class C implements Instantiation[C] {
  override def newWith(args):C
}
```

and now in the shared logic you can call newWith() to return the correct type

Comment: The OP is asking about Kotlin, not Scala (which your answer appears to be using).